# Android - Camera Id is empty after 6-7 hours of continues camera capture with 5 sec interval

Tags: android, television

I take a camera snapshot every 5 seconds, but after running for a few hours say 6-7 hours continuously, then camera ID starts to return as empty, and even if I try to connect with id '0' it's not able to detect any camera hardware.

I'm using an Android Mini TV Stick with a webcam camera connected to its USB slot.

**Logs:**

```
CameraService::connect call (PID -1 "com.poc.camvision", camera ID 0) for HAL version default and Camera API version 1
CameraService           cameraserver                         E  CameraService::connect X (PID 5483) rejected (invalid camera ID 0)
CameraBase              com.poc.camvision               W  An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8): '4: validateConnectLocked:850: No camera device with ID "0" available'
CameraPreview           com.poc.camvision               E  failed to open Camera
System.err              com.poc.camvision               W  java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
System.err              com.poc.camvision               W   at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:546)
System.err              com.poc.camvision               W   at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:392)
```